# How to create a cvs file merging results of a survey loop in R? Possible problem with read.table()

Tags: r, csv, templates, wav, read.table

I have some audio WAV files of frogs and 5 'chirp' templates that I had created to detect frog chirps within these files. I then created a loop (hopefully successfully) to make R use all the templates and go through the folder with the frog files by itself to search for the chirps (I cannot do it manually as there are 30,000+ frog files, though at the moment the folder only has 20 frog files in it for simplicity).

After the (hopefully correctly written) loop, I am trying to have R put the results into csv files. This is where I am running into trouble. I have managed to have R create an excel file titled 'all' but there is no data inside it.

The code may be a little messy to a much more practiced eye, but I am an R novice and when I attempt to "neaten" it up it no longer works... I will try to explain the parts of it in #'s case it's too messy though.

[This is the whole code in case there are relevant bits in it.](https://codeshare.io/bvgYqM) (Side note: template 5 throws up some warnings but I *think* it works).

[DropBox link to files if needed.](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/75itv9hf781n0wdgxbs7w/h?dl=0&rlkey=mh6av0u9tolg4czb8dxsthh9k)

**Attempting to create csv files for the detections** (this part and the loop are based off of code my supervisor had previously used for similar research). Various errors come up in this part that I have tried to solve but then I end up with new errors. The error `giving up` did make me laugh though.

```
setwd("H:/TESTING_R/detections") 
# change the wd for the detections - this seemed to help... but could be totally wrong

# Report the total time to do matching in all surveys
format(difftime(Sys.time(),begin.t,units='m'))

filenames <- list.files() 
# read all files in detections folder

temp <- do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, read.csv, header =
TRUE))
# brings up an error
```

The following error appears:

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
> first five rows are empty: giving up

This I *kind of* understand - the first file in that folder has no chirps, so the 5 templates should all find nothing. However, I still need the code to tell me there's nothing (it's important for establishing activity levels).

**Any help or advice anyone reading this has to give is greatly appreciated. Thank-you.**

Comment: You seem to think we will be able to offer solutions or debugging assistance by looking at error messages from functions we have never used before. You should back up to the first areas of difficulty and put just one of the WAV files in a Dropbox or public GoogleDocs website and see if people can get the first few lines of code to run properly. Then inspection of the results can be done.

Comment: Hi @IRTFM . Thank-you for the advice. The error messages don't mean a lot to me as I'm relatively new to R but I figured it was best to include them in case they held information someone else could understand/needed. Advice given on posing a question is to be as thorough as possible so I didn't want to leave anything out. I'll add a DropBox link to a small sample of the files as you suggest, thank-you :)

Comment: The advice is actually to provide a [MCVE]. Your code and question did not look "minimal". I will install the named packages and see if the file can be downloaded.

Comment: Hi @IRTFM :) Thank-you for the clarification. I've taken the advice on board and put all the code, bar the csv bit, into a codeshare link. I added it in case it was relevant, but I can see how messy/long-winded that would make a question look. Hope it looks better now :)

Comment: The link: https://www.dropbox.com/home/Frogs/TESTING_R assumes that we have logged in to your account. When followed it will generally give the error message "folder .../FROGS/  not found". You need to figure out how to construct a public folder on Dropbox and give access to it in a manner that has a chance of success.

Comment: My silly mistake, sorry! [Fixed](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/75itv9hf781n0wdgxbs7w/h?dl=0&rlkey=mh6av0u9tolg4czb8dxsthh9k) now hopefully! :)